# Using System.Threading.Channels with different TRead/TWrite

Tags: c#, .net, system.threading.channels

[Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1) are instantiated using the static methods `CreateUnbounded<TType>` or `CreateBounded<TType>`. The created channel will accept writes and emit reads of `TType`.

In my use case I want a channel that writes `TType` but emits `objects`. It looks like this would be possible, as there is a type [`Channel<TWrite, TRead>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1) so essentially I would like a `Channel<TWrite, object>`. Is there a way for me to create this instance? See screenshot below

[image: Desired instance]

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ is an introduction to Channels - this could probably help you (and everybody that finds this question)

Comment: If you're writing inputs typed as `TType` then the output will also be `TType` - why would you want to emit `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

`ChannelReader<T>` is an `abstract class` which (fortunately) doesn't have any blockers like an `internal` ctor, so anyone can subclass `ChannelReader` and specify their own `T`.

...though I honestly can't think of any good reason to want to use `ChannelReader<Object>` as you're losing type-safety.

But anyway, like so:

```cs
void Main()
{
    Channel<String> stringChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<String>();
    
    ChannelReader<String> rdr = stringChannel.Reader;
    
    // Usage:
    
    ChannelReader<Object> objectRdr_1 = new ObjectChannelReader<String>( rdr );
    
    // or:
    
    ChannelReader<Object> objectRdr_2 = rdr.ToObjectChannelReader();
}

public static class ObjectChannelReader
{
    public static ChannelReader<Object> ToObjectChannelReader<T>( this ChannelReader<T> typedReader )
    {
        if( typedReader is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(typedReader));
        
        return new ObjectChannelReader<T>( typedReader );
    }
}

public sealed class ObjectChannelReader<T> : ChannelReader<Object>
{
    private readonly ChannelReader<T> innerReader;
    
    public ObjectChannelReader( ChannelReader<T> innerReader )
    {
        this.innerReader = innerReader ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerReader));
    }

    public override Boolean CanCount   => this.innerReader.CanCount;
    public override Boolean CanPeek    => this.innerReader.CanPeek;
    public override Int32   Count      => this.innerReader.Count;
    public override Task    Completion => this.innerReader.Completion;

    //
    
    public override Boolean TryPeek( [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out Object item )
    {
        if( this.innerReader.TryPeek( out T? typedItem ) )
        {
            return ( ( item = typedItem ) != null );
        }
        else
        {
            item = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override Boolean TryRead( [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out Object item )
    {
        if( this.innerReader.TryRead( out T? typedItem ) )
        {
            return ( ( item = typedItem ) != null );
        }
        else
        {
            item = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override async ValueTask<Boolean> WaitToReadAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
    {
        return await this.innerReader.WaitToReadAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    
    // No need to reimplement `ReadAllAsync` or `ReadAsync` btw.
}
```